# TSQL verify sort order / UNION ALL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, temp-tables, union-all

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 1 AS a,'test1' as b, 'query1' as c
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS a,'test22' as b, 'query22' as c
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS a,'test2' as b, 'query2' as c
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS a,'test3' as b, 'query3' as c
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS a,'test4' as b, 'query4' as c
) As sample
FOR XML RAW

END
```

1. Can we guarantee that the stored procedure returns results in given order?
2. Normally it says when we insert these select query to temporary table we can't guarantee its inserting order. So we have to use order by clause. But most of time it gives same order. Can we enforce to give it some different order? Is this related with clustered and non clustered indices.
3. In second case can we enforce inserting order by adding Identity column?

Comment: Guarantee order? **Sure!** Just add an `ORDER BY` clause to your final output .... In any RDBMS, you do **NOT** have any guarantee of ordering **UNLESS** you explicitly specify an `ORDER BY`. It might *look like* it returns in order of the clustering key or something - but there's **NO GUARANTEE**. If you need ordering - use `ORDER BY`. Done.

Comment: No I just need to check whether it works without ORDER BY clause since this query doesn't insert data to temp table.

Comment: On `INSERT` - there's no ordering. The data is just inserted. On `SELECT`, if you need ordering - **use** `ORDER BY` - simple as that.

Comment: Can you explain more on behind logic why we need ORDER BY and for me this shows Stored Procedure gives same output. Is there way to enforce to return another order. I'm checking whether I need to check sort order in old Stored Procedures or not.

Comment: It's just how the RDBMS work - unless you **explicitly** specify an `ORDER BY`, the engine is at liberty to return the data in any way it chooses. So if you **need ordering** - specify an `ORDER BY` - simple as that. Just get used to it.

Comment: See [Bad habits to kick - relying on undocumented behavior](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior) by Aaron Bertrand - in the middle of the article, he has a section on "Ordering without ORDER BY" - read it and embrace it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59326/discussion-between-littleone-and-marc-s).

Answer (score 1):

When you insert data, SQL refers to it as a set. When even writing data to disc it tries to take minimum space and starts inserting rows in free pages it finds in non-uniform extents at first. So when you query data the result depends on the order of the information which is in the cash and the order of the information which is read from hard disc. I think it is  almost impossible to predict that orders as it depends on the work of OS , other programs and so on.